# Using an Excel formula to read a date corresponding to a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please see the screenshot of my schedule below.

I need a formula that will populate the END_DATE column with the date corresponding to the very last (rightmost) 'x' for each row..

Is there a way to read the rightmost 'x' in a row, and populate a cell with the date above that 'x'?

[image: Screenshot of Schedule]

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

PJ

Answer (score 1):

Updated based on @Dan's very correct feedback

You can use Array/CSE formula:

```
=INDEX($E$4:$K$4, 1, MAX(IF(E5:K5="X",COLUMN(E5:K5)-(COLUMN(E5)-1))))
```

**Using Ctrl+Shift+Enter to enter that in.** This will find the max column number that contains an `X` and subtract 3 from it (assuming the range we are searching is `D2:J2`, otherwise the `-3` will have to be adjusted to compensate. Then using `Index()` to find the corresponding value for that column.

[image]

Comment: Should be `A2:A8` so targets a specific row (op has multiple x's per row). Also you have to subtract the column number of the first x-1 as well. Your's works because the first x is in row 1 so you need to subtract 0 but OP doesn't have it starting in column 1.

Comment: Oh. I see. I misread the question. That this should go grab the max column for the range. But it is just a row.

Comment: @Dan I get what you're saying.. but I don't know how to modify the formula to reflect this LOL

Comment: @user2127447 I just updated the answer to reflect Dan's feedback and your question now that I'm "Getting" it.

Comment: @JNevill exactly right :) I would change the hardcoded 3 to point to the first cell though maybe so instead of `-3` have `-COLUMN(D2)+1`. that way it is robust to being moved around the sheet.

Comment: I couldn't get your new formula to work sadly @JNevill. For me the Xs are in E5 to N9, and the dates are from E4 to N4.

Comment: =INDEX($E$4:$N$4, 1, MAX(IF(E5:N5="X",COLUMN(E4:N4)-3))) is what I'm using but I get #VALUE

Comment: @user2127447 I have updated the answer for your cell range, I have also incorporated Dan's suggestion to use the Column() of the first cell in the range to make it more movable. Make sure you you use Ctrl+Shift+Enter to enter this end so it gets the little squirrelly brackets around it `{=INDEX($E$4:$K$4, 1, MAX(IF(E5:K5="X",COLUMN(E5:K5)-(COLUMN(E5)-1))))}` and it will be properly evaluated as an array formula.

Comment: Tried this too but still get #VALUE!, sorry guys:

=INDEX($E$4:$N$4, 1, MAX(IF(E5:N5="X",COLUMN(E5:N5)-(COLUMN(E5)-1))))

Comment: And you are entering it in as an array formula? (Sorry for asking, but it's the only thing I can think of that will cause that error).

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative to an array or CSE formula you can use aggregate which performs array like operations within the aggregate function.  Adjust the references to suit your needs, but avoid using full row/column references within aggregate due to the array like calculations it performs.

This solution uses a combination of INDEX and AGGREGATE

```
=INDEX($4:$4,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN($E5:$K5)/($E5:$K5="x"),1))
```

I used the above formula in the yellow cells shown in the example below.

[image: POC]

Comment: Hi. Your formula is giving me the 4th date after the actual end date.. it's like it finds the x and then chooses the 4th cell after the x:

=INDEX($E$4:$N$4,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN($E6:$N6)/($E6:$N6="x"),1))

Comment: You changed it from $4:$4 to $E$4:$N$4.  Try it again with the $4:$4.